# Problems with admin login magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm passing through a problem and I think you can help me.

About 2 hours ago my admin has stopped working. The problem is that when I try to log in, seems like everything is OK , however I receive a 302 code, my screen still showing the log in screen and my URL redirects to the right place.

I have one PC logged in and works perfectly, but all the other, in all browsers shows the same problem.

Is anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem and I solved it by deleting all files in /var/session . I think it's because too many session in Magento!

and for security, I changed 'Use HTTP only' to 'No' in 'Session Cookies Management' of the 'Web' settings after I can loggin again..

I found this solution on the internet:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel

by @user3213786